# EasyMock - Can I detect less call than expected?

Tags: easymock

I try to learn EasyMock 3.2 by refactoring tests using jMock. Excuse me if the answer is obvious, but currently I cannot find it. I know there is a 'strict' mock which detects if the order of expected calls is wrong. But I was surprised that I don't get an error if some expectations are left. Example:

```
// This test passes as expected

@Test
public void connectShouldPass() {
    expect(sessionMock.setTimeout(10000)).andReturn(true);
    replay(sessionMock);
    sessionMock.setTimeout(10000);
}

// Here I would expect an fail but it passes too

@Test
public void connectShouldPass() {
    expect(sessionMock.setTimeout(10000)).andReturn(true);
    expect(sessionMock.setTimeout(10000)).andReturn(true);
    replay(sessionMock);
    sessionMock.setTimeout(10000);
}
```

Is it possible to check (maybe in the @After method) if more expectations were defined than called?
Thanx, Andi

Comment: Stupid me, found it: EasyMock.verify(mock) does the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[OP found their own answer. Providing answer as an answer, rather than a comment]*

`EasyMock.verify(mock)` does the job.